# Can i get the data from the post api in ionic?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m using the POST API in my ionic3 application. Here’s the problem, As i’m giving an image to POST API and getting some output **(string value not JSON )** from that API. But how can i get the output

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: base64 encoded image or url

Comment: @Ari https://github.com/ksujanpaul/IonicTree

Comment: i'm using the base64 encoded image @Utpaul

Comment: which file you face problem ...

Comment: please mention which file you face problem and data formate ..